# web development without the knowledge of client side scripting or programming?

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much HTML and CSS should server side developer know?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/how-much-html-and-css-should-server-side-developer-know)

What will happen if someone wants to be a web developer but not interested to learn the client side scripting or programming. I am asking this question, because I think it is not possible, but a few days back, I had an argument with one of my rigid programmer friend. I could not make him understand. Do you guys agree with me? I believe that without the good client side knowledge, it is impossible to be a good web developer.

Comment: while telling the server side scripting, I am also telling about javascript and its framework like jquery

Comment: good web developer? yes.  cool web developer? no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment and in addition to [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/how-much-html-and-css-should-server-side-developer-know/95343#95343) to [How much HTML and CSS should server side developer know?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/how-much-html-and-css-should-server-side-developer-know), I would say that again, it depends on the projects and the companies.

There are projects which would require **the same person to do everything** from visual design to database management. If you want to work in the companies where **you have to know JavaScript**.

There are other projects with a **strict separation between who does what**. If you have a chance to work for such company, then you have to know your own domain of interest very well, but **you don't have to be an expert in what is done by your colleagues** (since in all cases it's hardly possible to be expert in everything related to the web development). But chances are that in those companies, **they would rather hire a person who knows well his own domain, but is also more or less familiar with the other domains**.

Comment: What If i want to be a freelancer?

Comment: @Pankouri for freelance to get the *widest range of jobs* they should know everything from *web design to database management*

Comment: If you want to be a freelancer, the #1 thing you need to know is how to get work...

Comment: I think this is the best comment!

Comment: I'd rather get 3 experts with different areas of focus than a DBA who likes to do graphics.

Comment: @Jeff O: I hope you do, since it is the only way to obtain a high quality product. Unfortunately, most companies don't do that; partially because hiring three experts is much more expensive than one non-expert who does everything.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on if you are okay with being dependent on another developer to make a complete web application product. If the web developer doesn't want that dependency (which I don't know any that would), then yes, client-side technology is extremely important.